# How to specify user using @ if the comp is not part of any domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows, runas

I want to run a command as an administrator. So I use runas command. And I want to specify the user using `@` character.

Is that possible as the computer (Windows7) is not part of any domain?

```
Examples:
> runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
> runas /profile /env /user:mydomain\admin "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
> runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""
```

I tried

- administrator@computer_name
- administrator@workgroup
- administrator@our_company_name
- administrator@computers_ip

and nothing worked. `computer_name\administrator` works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not available for non-domain user accounts. You must use the `computer\username` syntax for local user accounts.

The `name@domain` syntax is a User Principal Name. This is a feature of Active Directory; it used for specifying user accounts within a domain. It is not available for local user accounts since there is no associated domain suffix.

I've looked for documentation specifying this, but the best I can find is [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977279.aspx), which says:

> In a Windows 2000 domain, an account can have a user principal name in addition to its SAM account name.

Implicitly, this means that workgroup accounts do not have UPNs.

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation. I thought it would be the case but hoped not to be :-)

Answer (score 0):

So why not just use `computer_name\administrator?`

This is standard convention and you may look into your environmental variables if this is an itch your can't scratch.